# Push Notification Issue in Adhoc Distribution

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Hello I am new to IPhone.

I am working on Iphone app which receives push notifications successfully with development environment,but didn't receive notifications in adhoc distribution.

I have both certificates i.e development & production.

Can anyone tell me what am I missing?

Answer (score 44):

*As I posted yesterday as answer to the same question: ([prev. answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737343/push-notification-issue-in-adhoc-distribution/7737640#comment9416006_7737640))*

I've similar problems. After making some test I reached the following conclusions:

1. If app (that was compiled with `development provision profile`) is installed than such device has `development token` and you should sent pushes to such device using `development certificate`.
2. If app (that was compiled with `distribution provision profile`) is installed than such device has `production token` and you should sent pushes to such device using `production certificate`.

And, If your app is not yet published, I think that `APNS` will not accept `production certificate`, so probably you won't be able to send push to your ad-hoc apps.

What you can do? For example, sent app to your testers that compiled with `development certificate`.

**UPDATED:**
I've learned this question one more time and found some interesting information:

1. Download your `Ad-hoc provision profile`.
2. Open provision profile from 1. with text editor.
3. Search for lines 
   `<key>aps-environment</key>
       <string>production</string>`
4. Check the value of the key `aps-environment`. Is it equal to `production?`
5. If yes then you should send to your ad-hoc apps push notification with `production certificate`.

   If the value is `development` then you should send to your ad-hoc apps push notification with `development certificate`.
6. Now open iOS Provisioning Portal -> [App IDs](http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/bundles/index.action). Select your app.
7. Check if `Production Push SSL Certificate` is enabled.

If this didn't help you then try to update your ad-hoc provisioning profile.

Comment: I think u are not clear with what i said,it works for development profile but not for adhoc distribution.I am also using `pushmebaby` app for generating notification.Thanks

Comment: I understand you clearly. Read my second point: 2. If your app is not published in AppStore I'm not sure that you can use production certificate.

Comment: I have also tested with development certificate & adhoc ditribution profile but it still didn't show up anything.

Comment: You should try: dev provision profile + dev certificate. Ad-hoc provision profile + dev certificate won't work. Do you read my post? =)

Comment: Why my development token and production token are the same?

Comment: Thx for your reply. Are the device tokens with the same length equals to 64 characters?

Comment: Adhoc distribution will work with production apn certificates even if app has not been but into store.  You will need to generate your production certificates for APN and then regenerate your adhoc distribution certificate.

Answer (score 2):

There are severeral checklist that one should keep in mind while testing pushnotification for development environment. Most of them are already mentioned above. But this is one thing THAT SOLVED MY PROBLEM and i would like to share. I hope it helps someone. And that is:

**Please be aware of the device token-ID, which is different for the development && Production environment .**

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
       NSString *deviceTokenStr = [[[[deviceToken description]
                                      stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"<" withString: @""]
                                     stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @">" withString: @""]
                                    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];
       UIAlertView *alert= [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:deviceTokenStr message:Nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Push notifications are a headache sometimes and are made up of many elements. If you miss something on the way, your PNS won't work and it will be very difficult to understand why. As a rule of thumb, view the following checklist:
- Push certificate and private key were generated correctly with the correct App ID (the same one that the provisioning profile is attached to).
- Both the certificate and private key are taken from the same, downloaded PNS certificate.
- Both files were correctly concatenated into a .pem file.
- Your application handles push notifications as they come in, while the app is active.

In any case, I recommend following a good tutorial, such as this: http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/programming-apple-push-notification-services word for word. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for tutorial,I have followed all the steps.I don't need .pem file as I am using `pushmebaby` app which requires only certificates.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same thing and spent quite some time trying to figure it out. I generated a new production certificate, created an Ad-Hoc provisioning profile (so that I could test with the push notification going through production) and nothing was working at all.

I fixed the push script (server-side) accordingly (using the new generated .pem files and connecting to ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195). The script was telling me that the notification was delivered but my device wasn't actually getting it.

Turns out the problem was really silly! Apparently the device tokens change when using the application with the new certificate (either that or through Ad-Hoc). I can only speculate the reason as to why they changed, but all I know is that once I grabbed the correct token and used my test script to send a notification to the device, I got it!

Comment: +1. I also had to use ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195(needed to remove sandbox) and had to use device token for production certificate.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the guess from Nekto...

> And, If your app is not yet published, I think that APNS will not accept production certificate, so probably you won't be able to send push to your ad-hoc apps.

In the meantime I can confirm that it is possible to receive push notifications on ad-hoc apps, even if the app is not published yet.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you cannot send notifications to an Ad Hoc build with a development certificate. As you can imagine this scenario is ok UNTIL you release the app. Once the app is released sending notifications to the ad hoc build containing the production Cert will also send them out to your app holders. The way I got around this was:

1. Create a new app in Apple that is the same baseline as the app in itunes.
2. Create a new production key and cert for this "phantom" app.
3. Build the new app with the new production key and test with that build.

Now you will have an app you can build to specifically test notifications. Not an elegant solution but it works.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, creating a separate bundle  is a legitimate mechanism for beta testing with platforms such as HockeyApp.

Answer (score 0):

I have just overcome a very similar problem and it turned out to be something that probably should've been obvious but I'll post it here just in case anyone else is as daft as me.

I'm using `MoonAPNS` and could receive development notifications but not production. 
After several days of going around in circles I came back to this line:

```
PushNotification push = new PushNotification(true, p12file, p12password);
```

Having previously disregarded `true` parameter, a debug through the server code showed this was setting whether or not to use the Sandbox server - D'Oh! Switched it to `false` and all was well.

Moral of the story: don't forget to point your notifications at the non-Sandbox server!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and after a lots of testes finally i had got what's the problem.

That's because the apple production apns server not allow the P12 file that contain the data of private key any more. But the development apns server will accept the P12 file what ever if contain the private key.

So when you export the P12 file from keychain just only select your Production Certificate file without the private key and you will got the notifications on your adhoc app (even if not published).

Answer (score 0):

Answer for 2016.10.13

I have similar issue that after I change key following tutorial:
https://support.magplus.com/hc/en-us/articles/203808718-iOS-Creating-a-Push-Notification-Certificate

But still couldn't work
After I check server code and found that

The ssl: `ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195`
Must be change to `ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195`

After change that, I can receive notification